# R markdown files overlap figures when parallelized using Makefile

Tags: r, parallel-processing, makefile, knitr, r-markdown

I've created a simple example showing the problem I currently have.

I have a R-markdown file, named example.Rmd, containing the following code

````
```{r}
plot(rnorm(10000))
```
````

and a Makefile file with the following content

```
all : example01.html example02.html

example01.html : example.Rmd
    Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2html(input='example.Rmd', output='example01.html')"

example02.html : example.Rmd
    Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2html(input='example.Rmd', output='example02.html')"
```

If I run the Makefile file sequentially

```
make
```

there is no problem.

If I run the makefile in parallel

```
make -j 2
```

the chunks generated by knit2html function overlap and both html files contains the same image.

Any suggestion? I've been searching for a solution but I've found nothing.

Comment: put your Rmds in their own directory

Comment: There is only one Rmd file, not two. One R-markdown file that is used to generate two different html files.

Comment: put a symbolic link to the single document from the other directory

Comment: Karl, thank you for your response, but my problem is not related with directories, all files are properly detected. My main problem is that when I execute knit2html function in parallel both instances save the plot in the same folder figures/ and one instance overwrites the other because they are using the same name for figure, which is 'unnamed-chunk-1.png'. If possible, I need to solve this particular problem.

Comment: if you put Rmd in separate directories, the filenames will not clash. You will get unnamed-chunk-1.png in each directory, right ?

Comment: Now, I understand your point. The problem is that I have the makefile in one directory and the figure/ folder, which contains the unnamed-chunk-1.png, is created in the directory where makefile is. So, doesn't matter where I put the Rmd files that the chunks are saved on figure/ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea of Karl, I've written a possible solution.

```
all : example01.html example02.html

example01.html : example.Rmd
    mkdir -p dir_$@ 
    Rscript -e 'library(knitr); opts_knit$$set(base.dir = "dir_$@"); knit2html(input="example.Rmd", output="dir_$@/$@")'
    mv dir_$@/$@ .
    rm -r dir_$@

example02.html : example.Rmd
    mkdir -p dir_$@
    Rscript -e 'library(knitr); opts_knit$$set(base.dir = "dir_$@"); knit2html(input="example.Rmd", output="dir_$@/$@")'
    mv dir_$@/$@ .
    rm -r dir_$@
```

There are two modifications respect to initial code.

1. As Karl commented, I've included the line opts_knit$set(base.dir= "dir_example0?.html") in such a way the figure folder is create in that path.
2. I've swap " and ' symbol in Rscript -e command as commented [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/162)

Parallel execution

```
make -j 2
```

works fine.